# Populating HTML table data to a form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show my HTML table data to a form. When the function showDetails execute i.e when I click on the id I am getting the undefined values to the form from the table.

Comment: You shouldn't use HTML to store your data. Data storage should be separated from data presentation. I'd recommend you store your data in a global object that you can use to populate both your table and your form.

Comment: Hi! That sure is a lot of code you posted... Do think it would be possible to trim it down a bit? Try include only the relevant parts.. For example, we only need a sample of the HTML and not entire elements. Finally, please add some formatting to the code - it'll make it much much easier for someone to read (and possibly assist).

Comment: I think that this should be implemented in a server-side language because it would be much cleaner and more effective.

Comment: Use something like jsflle (http://jsfiddle.net/WH5gt/) to show your full code.. Don't use stackoverfolw to give all the code.. Put the heart of the code in stackoverflow, so we can understand it easily.

Comment: @ Asad thanks for getting back. Can u suggest me how to populate the data to a form. Please point my mistake as u said

Comment: @Ruwantha thanks for ur reply. How to populate this table data to a form. Any idea behind this

Comment: I may be able to help you. But as I mention in earlier, It is tedious to read all your code. Just simplify the your problem. Then even someone else could help you.